# How to correctly use 'routerLink' with model varaibles

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Trying to bind a routerLink from data bound to the template's class.  The template syntax appears to be correct according to the angular.io docs.  Have tried ROUTER_PROVIDERS and ROUTER_BINDINGS (both remain a mystery) at both the application and component level to no avail.  My code throws the 'helpfull' error: `TypeError: linkParams.reduce is not a function in [[ 'ClassDetail', {id: class._id} ] in ]`

template:

```
<div class="container" >
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 block" *ngFor="#class of classes | async">
      <h2>{{class.title}}</h2>
      <p>{{class.description}}</p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" routerLink="[ 'ClassDetail', {id: class._id} ]" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Without routerLink' this renders fine.

route configuration:

```
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/', component: Home, name: 'Index' },
  { path: '/home', component: Home, name: 'Home' },
  { path: '/about', component: AboutComponent, name: 'About' },
  { path: '/classes/:id', component: ClassDetailComponent, name: 'ClassDetail'}
])
```

Comment: You have to enclose `routerLink` in brackets : `[routerLink]=...`

Comment: Eagle eye Eric, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like that;

```
<p>
  <a class="btn btn-default"
     [routerLink]="[ 'ClassDetail', {id: class._id} ]" role="button">
    View details &raquo;
  </a>
</p>
```

As a matter of fact `router-link` is a directive in Angular2 . See this [link](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/RouterLink-directive.html)  in the documentation.

It must be configured with a bindable input (that's why you need to add the straight brackets). This allows to give a parameter to the directive. For more see the section "Configure the directive with binding" in the attribute directive doc: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/attribute-directives.html.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: yeh, got my syntax wrong, as Eric pointed out... all good, thanks.